# SimpleXML, iteration on all element

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml, iteration

I have a stock report file (coming from an outer source, therefore I can't modify in any way) and I would like to iterate over all elements (I have to save them into a MySQL table). As I see the $xml->Stockfile is an array of objects (2 items), so I tried to put it into an array.

For some reason the `$myarray` contains only the first element after the `$myarray = $xml->StockFile` assignment.

here is my code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("../docs/stock.xml"); 
print_r($xml);
$myarray = $xml->StockFile;
print_r($myarray);
```

stock.xml:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <StockFile>
    <MatrixID>1533</MatrixID>
    <Brand>myBrand</Brand>
    <ProductCode>001</ProductCode>
    <RRP>29.99</RRP>
    <Image2Name />
    <Image3Name />
  </StockFile>
  <StockFile>
    <MatrixID>1534</MatrixID>
    <Brand>myBrand</Brand>
    <ProductCode>002</ProductCode>
    <RRP>29.99</RRP>
    <Image2Name />
    <Image3Name />
  </StockFile>
</NewDataSet>
```

Why I'm getting only one item instead of all?
What should I do do retrieve the whole array?

Comment: OK, I figured out how to make it work:
foreach($xml->StockFile as $value) {
  echo $value->MatrixID . "\n";
  echo $value->Brand . "\n";
  echo $value->ProductCode . "\n";
  echo $value->RRP . "\n\n";
};
Still don't understand what is happened with the rest of the array after the $myarray assignment.

Comment: It's not an array, but an object. Foreach can work on a lot of things, not only arrays. And then those things (objects) can tell foreach what to do when used with it. Also I recommend the follwing tutorial to get into simplexml: [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the last two lines to

```
foreach ($xml->StockFile as $nextStockFile) {
    print_r ($nextStockFile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, do you know why is there only one item instead of all?

Comment: Cheers, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Take care with SimpleXMLElement. It has a lot of magic. Know the magic or get puzzled by `print_r` or `var_dump` or similar output. Your example extended:

```
$myarray = $xml->StockFile;
print_r($myarray); # shows one element

# foreach has both elements:
foreach($myarray as $name => $stockfile)
{
    echo $name, ":\n", $stockfile->asXML(), "\n\n";
}
```

Even though it is the same variable (`$myarray`) it behaves differently depending on context it is used in. Inside a `foreach` the `SimpleXMLElement` (that is the type of that object) will provide an iterator over the child-elements named `StockFile` as specified here:

```
$myarray = $xml->StockFile;
```

However using that variable in some kind of single context, it will for example return the inner string of the *first* child-element with that name:

```
echo $myarray, "\n";
```

(which in your case is just some lines of whitespace).

See Demo: https://eval.in/83787

Running into this "trap" by SimpleXML is actually pretty common. I suggest to understand the basic usage by the example given in the manual:

- [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)

Comment: Thank you for revealing the secret :)